# Iterate and transform object in array

Tags: javascript, database, angular

From database i get:

```
"Data": [{
  "mainData": [{
    "_id": ObjectId("5ab63b22d012ea2bc0bb7e9b"),
    "date": "2018-03-24"
  }],
  "files": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5ab63b22d012ea2bc0bb7e9d"),
      "filename": "file-1521892130284.png",
      "path": "uploads\\file-1521892130284.png"
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5ab63b22d012ea2bc0bb7e9c"),
      "filename": "file-1521892130285.png",
      "path": "uploads\\file-1521892130285.png"
    }
  ]
}]
```

but I need transform above in something like this:

```
this.galleryImages = [
  {
    small: 'file-1521892130284.png'
  },
  {
    small: 'file-1521892130285.png'
  }
];
```

How better way to iterates some files path and push it exactly as demand gallery Images object? 
galleryImages - ngx-gallery from Angular.

Comment: where do you get the numbers of `'assets/1-small.jpg'`, or is it just the incremented index?

Comment: Use magic. That is all I can tell you from what you have posted here.

Comment: your response not matched with required `output`.

Comment: Why do `png` files become `jpg`, and with different paths, or is that irrevant and should the original path+filename be used? If the latter, please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49555045/edit) and improve that.

Comment: I changed it. Now it's ok, It was from exapmes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const ObjectId = (v) => v; // dummy implementation

const dbResponse = {"Data": [{
  "mainData": [{
    "_id": ObjectId("5ab63b22d012ea2bc0bb7e9b"),
    "date": "2018-03-24"
  }],
  "files": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5ab63b22d012ea2bc0bb7e9d"),
      "filename": "file-1521892130284.png",
      "path": "uploads\\file-1521892130284.png"
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5ab63b22d012ea2bc0bb7e9c"),
      "filename": "file-1521892130285.png",
      "path": "uploads\\file-1521892130285.png"
    }
  ]
},
]}

/* we get an array of "files" arrays */
const allFiles = dbResponse.Data.map(x => x.files)

/*
we map a files array to an array of {"small":...}
objects
*/
function getFilenames(files) {
  return files.map(keepOnlyFilename);
}

/*
we take an object like:
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5ab63b22d012ea2bc0bb7e9d"),
  "filename": "file-1521892130284.png",
  "path": "uploads\\file-1521892130284.png"
}
and we transform it to:
{
  "small": "file-1521892130284.png"
}
*/
function keepOnlyFilename(obj) {
  return {
    "small": obj.filename
  };
}

/* we put the above together as building blocks */
const final = allFiles.map(getFilenames);

console.log(final)
```

Comment: Thx, it works but when I have few array with object files I received it in one array

Comment: Then just omit the "flattening" of the nested array to keep it that way. Is that ok?

Comment: When I ommit "const flattened = allFiles.reduce( (prev, x) => prev.concat(x) )" I receive:
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0:{small: undefined}
1:{small: undefined}
length:2

Comment: I updated my answer to further explain with simpler functions

Answer (score 0):

Start by parsing your JSON using `var Data = JSON.parse(str);`

Then, create a new object `var galleryImage = [];` and iterate over the your Data array.

```
for(var i =0; i < Data.files.length; i++)
  galleryImages[i] = { small : Data.files[i].filename }
```

Comment: Thx, it works but when I have few array with object files it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For an array of all filenames, you need to iterate `Data` and the inner array of `files`. Then build new objects and map the inner result by reducing the outer array.

Method used:

- [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for the outer array with an array as start vlaue,
- a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for getting a single property of an object,
- [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) for merging of two arrays,
- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for getting a new object with the wanted renamed property as
- [short hand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

```js
function ObjectId(v) { return v; }

var $scope = { "Data": [{ "mainData": [{ "_id": ObjectId("5ab63b22d012ea2bc0bb7e9b"), "date": "2018-03-24" }], "files": [{ "_id": ObjectId("5ab63b22d012ea2bc0bb7e9d"), "filename": "file-1521892130284.png", "path": "uploads\\file-1521892130284.png" }, { "_id": ObjectId("5ab63b22d012ea2bc0bb7e9c"), "filename": "file-1521892130285.png", "path": "uploads\\file-1521892130285.png" }] }] },
    array = $scope.Data.reduce(
        (r, { files }) => r.concat(files.map(({ filename: short }) => ({ short }))),
        []
    );

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```